# How to plot regression transformed back on original scale with colored confidence interval bands?

Tags: r, plot, regression, transformation, confidence-interval

I would like to plot the line and the 95% confidence interval from a linear model where the response has been logit transformed back on the original scale of the data. So the result should be a curved line including the confidence intervals on the original scale, where it would be a straight line on the logit transformed scale. See code:

```
# Data
dat <- data.frame(c(45,75,14,45,45,55,65,15,3,85),
                  c(.37, .45, .24, .16, .46, .89, .16, .24, .23, .49))
colnames(dat) <- c("age", "bil.")               


# Logit transformation
dat$bb_logit <- log(dat$bil./(1-dat$bil.))

# Model
modelbb <- lm(bb_logit ~ age + I(age^2), data=dat)
summary(modelbb)

# Backtranform
dat$bb_back <- exp(predict.lm(modelbb))/ (1 + exp(predict.lm(modelbb)))

# Plot
plot(dat$age, dat$bb_back)
abline(modelbb)
```

What do I try here is to plot the curved regression line and add the confidence interval. Within `ggplot2` there is the `geom_smooth` function where the the linear model can be specified, but I could not find a way of plotting the predictions from the `predict.lm(my model)`.

I would also like to know how to add a coloured polygon which will represent the confidence interval as in the image below. I know I have to use function `polygon` and coordinates but I do not know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `predict` on an age range say `1:100`, specify `interval=` option for the CIs. Plotting with `type="l"` will smooth a nice curve. Confidence intervals then can be added using `lines`.

```
p <- predict(modelbb, data.frame(age=1:100), interval="confidence")
# Backtransform
p.tr <- exp(p) / (1 + exp(p))

plot(1:100, p.tr[,1], type="l", ylim=range(p.tr), xlab="age", ylab="bil.")
sapply(2:3, function(i) lines(1:100, p.tr[,i], lty=2))
legend("topleft", legend=c("fit", "95%-CI"), lty=1:2)
```

### Yields

[image]

---

### Edit

To get shaded confidence bands use `polygon`. Since you want two confidence levels you probably need to make one `predict`ion for each. The line will get covered by the `polygon`s, so it's better to make an empty `plot` first using `type="n"` and draw the `lines` at the end. (Note that I'll also show you some hints for custom axis labeling.) The trick for the `polygons` is to express the values back and forth using `rev`.

```
p.95 <- predict(modelbb, data.frame(age=1:100), interval="confidence", level=.95)
p.99 <- predict(modelbb, data.frame(age=1:100), interval="confidence", level=.99)
# Backtransform
p.95.tr <- exp(p.95) / (1 + exp(p.95))
p.99.tr <- exp(p.99) / (1 + exp(p.99))

plot(1:100, p.99.tr[,1], type="n", ylim=range(p.99.tr), xlab="Age", ylab="",
     main="", yaxt="n")
mtext("Tree biomass production", 3, .5)
mtext("a", 2, 2, at=1.17, xpd=TRUE, las=2, cex=3)
axis(2, (1:5)*.2, labels=FALSE)
mtext((1:5)*2, 2, 1, at=(1:5)*.2, las=2)
mtext(bquote(Production ~(kg~m^-2~year^-1)), 2, 2)
# CIs
polygon(c(1:100, 100:1), c(p.99.tr[,2], rev(p.99.tr[,3])), col=rgb(.5, 1, .2),
        border=NA)
polygon(c(1:100, 100:1), c(p.95.tr[,2], rev(p.95.tr[,3])), col=rgb(0, .8, .5),
        border=NA)
# fit
lines(1:100, p.99.tr[,1], ylim=range(p.99.tr), lwd=2)
#legend
legend("topleft", legend=c("fit", "99%-CI", "95%-CI"), lty=c(1, NA, NA), lwd=2,
       pch=c(NA, 15, 15), bty="n",
       col=c("#000000", rgb(.5, 1, .2), rgb(0, .8, .5)))
```

### Yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion!
This is good. However, I need that the y axis is between 0 and 1 (original scale of the data). When I also changed the age to range between 0 and 200 then the y axis was ranging between -30 and 30
I was also hoping to extract the prediction of the outer 95% CI for the model to produce a polygon than can be filled with grey colour.

Comment: @matrivi I forgot to backtransform, please see edit. For your filling approach you may want to look into `?polygon`, see e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36948706/6574038

Comment: Thanks! This was my first question in stack overflow and your answer was really helpful! I have edit my question to specify the type of polygon I need for my graph. I will continue investigating this as I could not figure out from the answer you suggested to check.

Comment: @matrivi Normally, in Stack Overflow we ask a new question instead of changing a question substantially, but I make an exception. See my extended answer.